# Biholomorphic maps between cotangent bundles with non-standard complex structures

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $X$ be a compact Kähler manifold. Let $\omega_i$ (i=1,2) be Kähler forms on $X$. Assume that $\psi:X\rightarrow X$ is a diffeomorphism such that $\psi^*\omega_2=\omega_1$.

Recall that each $\omega_i$ defines a complex structure on $T^*X$ as follows: locally let $f_i$ be a Kähler potential for $\omega_i$, then we have a diffeomorphism of T^*X:
$$
z\mapsto z+\partial f_i (\pi z),
$$
where $\pi:T^*X\rightarrow X$ is the bundle projection and $z\in T^*X$. Pulling back the standard complex structure on $T^*X$ along this map, we get a new complex manifold. The complex structure does not depend on the choice of $f_i$, denote the new complex manifold as $Y_i$. We may identify $X$ as a totally real submanifold of $Y_i$, namely, as the zero section.

Now assume that $\psi$ extends to a biholomorphic map 
$$
\Psi:Y_1\rightarrow Y_2.
$$

My question: is it true that $\psi$ is indeed holomorphic?